# Ubuntu 16.04 'Suspend when inactive for...' and 'Turn screen off when inactive for...' doesn't work when on battery power

Tags: suspend, battery, idle

Ubuntu 16.04 `Suspend when inactive for...` and `Turn screen off when inactive for...` doesn't work when system is **on battery power**.

Both of these work when plugged in and I can manually suspend (`systemctl suspend`) the system and wake it up again.

It's a Lenovo Ideapad U530 dual Win10 & Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem, but still don't have a solution. While trying to watch Netflix on battery I noticed that every 20 seconds the Netflix video menu pops up and the mouse pointer becomes visible. I unplugged the USB mouse and disabled the track pad and the touch screen, but still every 20 seconds something is causing a tiny mouse movement and this in turn causing the laptop not be able to sleep/suspend.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Linux kernel update (linux-image-4.13.0-26 and a dozen or so more packages) received on 2018-01-10 fixed my problem. 
Since that updated both 'Suspend when inactive for' and 'Turn screen off when inactive for' work when system is on battery power!